# Child widget goes out of parent widget boundary Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to resize font size according to widget dimensions and using FittedBox() for that purpose. When ever I change widget dimensions (width) dynamically the font also resizes but the issue is child widget is going out of the boundary of parent widget.

This is the UI design I am working on. There is a slider between two sides, on sliding that slider both the sides expand/contract or vice versa. I want to increase font size of the side which is expanding and decrease the font size which is contacting.
[UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doduH.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doduH.png)

Here is my code snippet

```html
 Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 30,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Qty',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.blue[200],
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Description',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Price',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Extend',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

And here is the screenshot of output.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KvJd.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KvJd.png)

Anyone help me how to solve this issue. Or suggest any other way to resize font according to change in widget dimensions (width) dynamically

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the `FittedBox`'s `fit` property to `BoxFit.fitHeight` or `BoxFit.contain`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. fitHeight and contain don't resize text on changing widget dimensions (width).

Comment: If you fit it using the width, it will always overlap. Do you have a target UI design? I would like to check.

Comment: Yes, attached the screenshot above. Kindly check it.

Comment: I think `BoxFit.fitHeight` or `BoxFit.contain` would suffice. Take note that the scaling is in both axes. Maybe you can just adjust the height to see the difference.

Comment: I've removed the height of this row and used contain property. It is working now, increasing/decreasing font size on sliding slider. But now the only issue is that initial font size is large i.e. before sliding slider and not reducing even I tried specific size.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the scaleDown property on the [BoxFit](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html), sounds like that is what you are looking for.

```
Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Qty',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

How it looks with scaleDown

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried scaleDown property. It doesn't resize text on changing widget dimensions. The text size remains unchanged for this property.

Comment: You have to increase the fontsize of your text, it only scales down and not up. If you are still having issues with this you could have a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text .